# How to log URL to a file only if it’s HTTP status code is 200?

Tags: command-line, bash, text-processing, grep, curl

I want to make a script so I can check if I can connect to several URL.

For example I do `curl -i -L --silent URL | grep "HTTP/2 200" >> *.txt`

I want to combine it with an if statement so I can do `if grep "HTTP/" 200" >> *.txt", then: grep "Location" >> *.txt`

So if it does grep "HTTP/2 200" then it should grep the "location" (URL) as well. I can't get it to work though.

Also I want to do `echo "-------------------------------------"` between every URL output so it shows like this in a file:

```
#URL1

HTTP(1)

URL(1)

#URL2

HTTP(2)

URL(2)
```

and so on.

thanks for every help.

Comment: Yep, possible ... `curl -i -L --silent URL | if grep -q "HTTP/2 200"; then grep "Location"; fi` ... But, please give examples to make your question clearer so we can help you better ... i.e. Be specific please.

Comment: did you think about `curl -i -L --silent URL | grep "HTTP/2 200" | grep "Location" >> *.txt` ? this may solve the fist part of your question.

Comment: Check the bash man pages for the && construct. execute what's after if the previous succeeded.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show some example output of `curl -i -L --silent URL` and the corresponding expected result in your output file.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the **HTTP response/status** and the **URL** saved to a file in the format you desire. then [`curl`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/curl.1.html#:%7E:text=curl%20is%20a%20tool%20to,to%20work%20without%20user%20interaction.) alone can do that ... It has the option `-w` or `--write-out`(*Which defines what to display on stdout after a completed and successful operation. The format is a string that may contain plain text mixed with any number of variables ... e.g. `-w "-----------\nStatus: %{http_code}\nURL: %{url}\n"`*) and if you redirect the rest of the output to e.g. `/dev/null` then you end up with a clean result of just what you want and you can then redirect that result and append it to a file called e.g. `url.txt` like so:

```
curl -o /dev/null -s -w "-----------\nStatus: %{http_code}\nURL: %{url}\n" https://askubuntu.com >> url.txt
```

If you have a list of URLs(*each on a new line*) in a file called e.g. `list.txt` like so:

```bash
$ cat list.txt
https://askubuntu.com/
https://unix.stackexchange.com/
https://notworkingurlblabla.com/
```

Then, you can check all the URLs in that file, filter-out **non** `200` status URLs and append the result to `url.txt` all at once e.g. like so:

```bash
xargs -n 1 <list.txt curl -o /dev/null -s -w "%{http_code} %{url}\n" | \
awk '{if ($1 == "200") printf "------------\nStatus: "$1"\nURL: "$2"\n"}' >> url.txt
```

You can also, obviously, use `awk` to filter output with a  single URL as well like so:

```bash
curl -o /dev/null -s -w "%{http_code} %{url}\n" https://askubuntu.com/ | \
awk '{if ($1 == "200") printf "------------\nStatus: HTTP "$1"\nURL: "$2"\n"}' >> url.txt
```

Comment: how can i output the HTTP 200 and Location to a file tho?

Comment: @dummyuser sadly no, i dont want both the HTTP status + the Location to get saved into the file. i Only want them to be saved if there is a HTTP2/2 200, but with your command it would save the Location anyway even if there is no http 200

Comment: @user2315 `curl -o /dev/null -s -w "%{http_code} %{url}\n" https://askubuntu.com/ | awk '{if ($1 == "200") printf "------------\nStatus: HTTP "$1"\nURL: "$2"\n"}' >> url.txt`

Comment: thank you for your fast answer. I need a little more help tho, i tried the second thing you have written with the xargs and the list.txt file. I copied everything exactly like you wrote it but it doesnt work for me, do i have to change some things from your original post?

Comment: @user2315 Do you have a file called `list.txt` that contains URLs like the example I show in my answer? ... It needs to be in the same working directory where you run the command.

Comment: @user2315 Oh, probably obvious but you need to copy the two lines xargs and awk together and paste them in the terminal at once ... It's just a one line broken down to two by the backslash "\" for readability purposes. :-)

Comment: Oh okay thank you. I have my script like this now: xargs -n 1 <url.txt curl -o /dev/null -s -w "%{http_code} %{url_effective}\n" | awk '{if ($1 == "200") printf "------------\nStatus: "$1"\nURL: "$2"\n"}' >> test.txt it doenst work for me with "url" tho so i tried using "url_effective", it doenst copy the output to the test.txt file tho. My file with all the URL`s is in the file "url.txt" so i changed that off aswell

Comment: I was missing the -i -L because i get 3 http status codes because of nginx but now it works thank you.